# Javascript : How to scroll horizontally to given position within an overflowed div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, slider, horizontal-scrolling

I have following situation

```
WRAPPER (100% width of page)
----------------------------------------------
|                                            |  
|                                            |
|     CONTENT (8000px width)                 |  
|                                            |  
|                                            |
----------------------------------------------
|     HORIZONTAL SLIDER FOR CONTENT          |
----------------------------------------------
```

Dragging the slider is moving thought the content.

I would like to ask how can i programatically trigger horizontal slider click to move for give position. Or how move to the given position on axis X.

I tried **scrollTo** but without the luck (it works only for document object.

Maybe use the anchors, but i would like the simplest solution.

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with scrollLeft(value)?

For more information on this please see the link https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/

Comment: Thank You very much, i did not know about this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery scrollLeft() method (or scrollLeft DOM property) on the container